# Can i set inside stroke in fabric js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am working on a fabricjs application & i need to set a inside stroke to object, it means apply stroke to a object without increase it's size.

eg if i apply strokeWidth 20 to 100*100 rect then it's size is also increase but i want if stroke is apply to object then size will also remain same

```js
var recta = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 10,
        top: 10,
        fill: '#000',
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        
    });

var rectb = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 150,
        top: 10,
        fill: '#000',
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        
    });
    canvas.add(recta, rectb);
rectb.set('stroke', '#f00');
rectb.set('strokeWidth', 20);
canvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas style="border:#000 1px solid" id="design-canvas" width="500" height="400">
<script type="text/javascript">
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('design-canvas');
    </script>
```

Is there is any way or trick to apply stroke without increase size

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it'd just be for rectangles, The best way would likely be too attach 4 lines which you update the positions based off of that rectangles x, y, width and height. You can then set the stroked width of those lines separately.

The other way would be too simply resize the owning element. Look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fabricjs/nXmTC/).

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false });

var circle, isDown, origX, origY;

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o){
  isDown = true;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  origX = pointer.x;
  origY = pointer.y;
  circle = new fabric.Circle({
    left: pointer.x,
    top: pointer.y,
    radius: 1,
    strokeWidth: 5,
    stroke: 'red',
    selectable: false,
    originX: 'center', originY: 'center'
  });
  canvas.add(circle);
});

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o){
  if (!isDown) return;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  circle.set({ radius: Math.abs(origX - pointer.x) });
  canvas.renderAll();
});

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o){
  isDown = false;
});
```

Comment: @rtawr ,for rectangle this can be done , but what we do in case of other shapes like circle, triangle SVG & etc

Comment: For SVG i'm not sure, but for Circle or Triangle it would be the same as for a rectangle, create a set of Lines which would act as a "Border" for the shape. For a circle you would need to approximate it as a set of lines.

For a SVG, you could roughly create another version of the SVG underneath the original, enlarge by a scaled value and set the colour to your border color It wouldn't be a perfect solution though.